# What is the most stress-resilient filesystem at the moment?

Tags: linux, filesystems, hard-disk

I'm looking for a filesystem that can handle IO in such a way that it puts the least amount of stress on a (regular) hard disk.
In other words: Keep the drive alive as long as possible

This is for home-usage, I just want to store regular files.
I don't need any "features" (cow, encryption, raid, compression, ...)
I don't even mind if atime, mtime, ctime, permissions and user/group are not (or incorrectly) saved.

I assume others will also have the same question and depending on the use-case the answer might be different.

My use-case would be (more or less):

- Files between 100 MB and 10GB
- Total filesystemsize between 2 and 20 TB
- Files will only be written and deleted, not modified
- Most operations will involve reading (files will be read 5 to 10 times between creation and deletion)
- Speed is not important

I assume that it's not only the total IO operations that matter, but also the location of the data.
I'm not an expert but i guess that a hard drive also dies faster if the needle constantly has to jump from one point of the drive to some other far-away point.
So self-defragmentation might be handy (unless that itself causes more stress on the drive then that it actually helps)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

F2FS was specifically created to minimize disk writes. exFAT (now supported natively by the Linux kernel) is also quite frugal in this regard. Lastly you can use ext2/ext4fs without a journal.

Most others Linux file systems require journalling which creates an addition strain on your storage.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's unlikely that the I/O patterns of different filesystems will affect your rotational hard drive's lifespan.  In particular, head seeks do not significantly contribute to hard drive wear because modern drives use electromagnetic [voice coils](https://www.petervis.com/gallery/hard/Hard%20Drive%20Recovery/Hard%20Drive%20Recovery%20Voice%20Coil%20Assembly.html).  The only seek-related wear is at the head pivot point, which doesn't tend to wear out.

You should avoid stopping and starting the drive unnecessarily.  The wear caused by drive spin-up is much more significant than any I/O patterns.

If your primary goal is really to maximize the lifespan of a single device, then the most impactful choice you can make is the manufacturer and model of the drive you buy.  You may find [BackBlaze's Hard Drive Data and Stats](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/hard-drive-test-data.html) useful for this.

If your primary goal is data durability, then you need backups.  If your primary goal is high availability, then you need RAID or some other form of redundancy.

As for filesystem choice, you have a relatively simple set of requirements.  If you only need to use it on Linux, I'd suggest using ext4.  It's mature, stable, very widely used, and you're unlikely to run into a kernel that doesn't support it.